# PHP alternating colors for each HTML table row

Tags: php, html, function, foreach

I need to make a **function** that returns two colors alternately.  For example, if my table is to have 3 rows, the colors should be blue-yellow-blue.

I need to make two tables, one by using **for** and the other by using **foreach**. If I make the second table, the first row's color cannot be the same as the first table's last row color. This is where I am in trouble.

I made it work like this, but if I make a new table I always have to increase `$i` by 1. I'm really new to PHP and I don't know how to write this better. This is an exercise from school course. Thanks for help in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>H01T05</title>
</head>
<body>


<?php

$tableContent = array("First row", "Second row", "Third row", "Fourth row", "Fifth row","Sixth row","Seventh row");


function backgroundColor($i) {
    if($i%2 == 0) {
        $color1 = "lightblue";
        return $color1;
    } else {
        $color2 = "yellow";
        return $color2;
    }
}
echo "<table>";
for($i=0;$i< sizeof($tableContent);$i++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td style=background-color:" . backgroundColor($i) . ">". $tableContent[$i] ."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<br>";

echo "<table>";
$i = 1;
foreach($tableContent as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td style=background-color:" . backgroundColor($i) .">" . $row . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $i++;
}

echo "</table>";



?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In `foreach` you can use get the index values. You don't need to increment manually. Try this: `foreach($tableContent as $index => $row)`. Don't use `$i` instead use `$index`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Didn't know that. This doesn't solve my problem though. My first table ends with the same color as the second table starts. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Your current output is exactly what you are wanting, isn't it?

Comment: I put the $i++; inside the beginning of the foreach loop and it works now just as I want it to! Thanks for help!